# Retrieve the id value from a table, to use it later

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am tryig to retrieve the value P_id (auto increment) from table P_identity to store it in table Communication. It appears that kind of error

> "Error :System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion
>   failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT P_id FROM P_identity
>   WHERE Amka = '15598970695'' to data type int."

How can I resolve it?

```
try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string pat_id = "SELECT P_id FROM P_identity WHERE Amka  = '" + TextBoxAmka.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(pat_id, conn);

            com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("");

            string insert_pacom = "insert into Communication (P_id,Address,Region,Town,TK,Mobile_number,Country,House_number,Email) values (@pa_id, @add, @nomos, @poli, @tk, @kinito, @xora, @oikia, @email) ";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insert_pacom, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pa_id", pat_id.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtadd.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomos", txtnomos.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poli", txttown.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tk", txttk.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xora", txtxora.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kinito", txtkinito.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oikia", txtoikia.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);


            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Τα στοιχεία αποθηκεύτηκαν επιτυχώς!')</script>");

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error :" + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Beware of [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)! You should never build SQL queries by concatenating string - especially when it includes user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to delete single quotes from

```
WHERE Amka  = '" + TextBoxAmka.Text + "'"
```

part as

```
WHERE Amka  = " + TextBoxAmka.Text
```

which `Amka`  column seems as a numerical value. And using `ExecuteNonQuery` seems pointless for a `SELECT` statement. You can use [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) if you wanna get the result values from your statement.

Or if your `SELECT` statement returns *only* one value, you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) which is exactly fits the situation.

```
int id = (int)com2.ExecuteScalar();
```

A few things more;

- Use parameterized queries for your `SELECT` statement as you did for `INSERT` statement.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.
- Do not use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Comment: it must be this way `WHERE Amka  = @Amka` and no other way

Comment: @GeneR Yeap, that's why I said `Use parameterized queries for your SELECT statement as you did for INSERT statement`

Comment: I did it, and now it says that : Error :System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: @natso If your `SELECt` statement return only one value, you can use `ExecuteScalar` instead. You will not need `ExecuteReader` if you get only one value. I gave a code sample. Check it.